# Use Gradle Kotlin DSL in visual studio code

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to use vscode to develop spring-boot application.

But, there's problem.

In vscode, build.gradle.kts intellisense is not working.

I installed may extensions. But, not solved.

Is there any extension supporting?

these are my extensions.

- gradle for java
- gradle language support
- language support for java(TM) by red hat
- kotlin
  ...

Comment: Related: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/632